# "...при постройке Стены погиблА/И нe одна тысяча китайцев"?

Tags: грамматика

"...при постройке Стены погибл**а** нe одна тысяча китайцев"

or

"...при постройке Стены погибл**и** нe одна тысяча китайцев"

Should the verb be in plural or singular in such cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"...при постройке Стены погибла нe одна тысяча китайцев"
The subject here is "тысяча", so the rest of the grammatical structure should be built around it.

Technically, you can use the verb in plural if you want to stress "the Chinese", but it sounds off and is not exactly grammatically correct. Some people would still use it like that though.

"При словах тысяча, миллион, миллиард сказуемое обычно согласуется по правилам согласования с подлежащими-существительными (в роде и числе), например: Тысяча книг поступила в школьную библиотеку; Миллион демонстрантов заполнил площади и улицы столицы."

Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm

Comment: Thanks, but can you cite some sources?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment.